# Вывод форматированноготелефона в TextView

Tags: android-sdk, android

Добрый день, возник такой вопрос:

Есть телефон и TextView для ввода в поле. Нужно чтобы в поле "Телефон", нельзя было ввести телефон типа "0000000..." Нужно четкого формата "+7/7/8 XXX XXX XX XX"

Т.Е. я представляю себе так, человек вводит в поле телефон, и он форматируется под указанный формат, если же формат не соответствует, то поле подсвечивается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам задал, сам и отвечу ))))

Воодщем вот - http://horribileru.blogspot.ru/2011/12/textedit.html
и вот - https://opentoolbox.devguard.com/svn/opentoolbox/trunk/android/commons/src/main/java/org/opentoolbox/android/commons/MaskedFormatter.java

И все работает так как надо )

Answer (score 1):

добавь `TextChangedListener` чтобы фильтровать введенные символы и автоматически добавлять дефисы в нужных местах